# Crop CMSampleBufferRef samples

Tags: ios, iphone, video-processing

I am using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to capture camera video. I would like to crop `CMSampleBufferRef` to make the final video square. But I can't find solution to do that. Do you have any ideas?

Please do not offer `AVAssetExportSession`.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use CoreImage to filter it, by taking advantage of ciimages initWithCVImageBuffer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentatively, you could try setting a dictionary on the something like the following with your `width` and `height`:

```
NSDictionary* videoSettingsDictionary = @{
    (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey : @(width),
    (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(height),
    AVVideoScalingModeKey : AVVideoScalingModeFit
};
[yourAVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettingsDictionary];
```

Supposedly, `AVVideoScalingModeFit` forces the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to `Crop to remove edge processing region; preserve aspect ratio of cropped source by reducing specified width or height if necessary.` ([link to AVF docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_73))

Comment: Interestingly enough, the documentation says only the key `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` is supported, yet the mentioned ones are honoured as well. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput/videoSettings)

Comment: Sadly it seems this no longer works. Attempting to set the video settings dictionary with the given keys prints `videoSettings dictionary contains one or more unsupported (ignored) keys: (AVVideoScalingModeKey, Height, Width)`.